# How can I fix IISNode internal server error? listen EACCESS permission denied

Tags: node.js, iis, iisnode

I added a node application as a website on IIS with a web config file and whenever I try to browse the website it gives this error:
[Error on web browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6aFh.jpg).
I have tried using the taskkill command to stop the process listening to this port and I also tried giving IIS_IUSRS user full permission on the root folder, but this issue persists

web.config file:
[config file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORent.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to find my way around this issue. I removed the application from IIS and I used pm2 to start the node application and I didn't encounter any error after using this approach.